# Access TransferSpreadsheet Command selecting custom range

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, range

So just for my background. No access training and I have to somehow set up barcoding, importing and creating ID cards (oh and updating lotus notes contacts through access! (still have no idea how I'm going to make that one work)) so sorry if my questions seem.... well idiotic.

Anyways, I'm trying to important a custom range of columns from a excel sheet into a table. This format should never change and is generated monthly and I just need to figure out how to set ranges for the columns I want.

here's my code:

```
  Private Sub Command143_Click()
Box1 = MsgBox("Importing information CANNOT be undone, are you sure you want to continue?(BE SURE TO BACK UP THE ORIGINAL TABLE FIRST!!!)", vbOKCancel, "Warning!!!")
If Box1 = vbOK Then
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, _
    "blarg", Me.Text138, True, "(range goes here)"
End If
End Sub
```

So far everything works great, just need to select custom ranges but I can't seem to get the synthax right. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on Access 2007:

```
Private Sub Command143_Click()
  Dim Box1
  Box1 = MsgBox("Importing information CANNOT be undone, are you sure you want to continue?(BE SURE TO BACK UP THE ORIGINAL TABLE FIRST!!!)", vbOKCancel, "Warning!!!")
  If Box1 = vbOK Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
      "blarg", Me.Text138, True, "B2:C5"
  End If
End Sub
```

Excel document, the first row of the Range B2:C5 will be used as field names of the resulting table:

[image] ====>

[image]